# How to erase a portion of stroke on Canvas in Windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Tags: silverlight, canvas, windows-phone-8.1

I am using InkPresenter to draw stroke on image using a canvas. It works great. Now I can erase any stroke which I want by touching any point of the stroke. But I need to erase a part of the stroke. I see several store wp apps can do that. How it is possible. here is my code.

```
Stroke NewStroke;
double strokeSize = 4;
Color drawingColor = Colors.White;
private enum EditState { Draw, Erase, Effect };
private void StartDrawing_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    try
    {
       if (crtState == EditState.Draw) {
          MyIP.CaptureMouse();
          StylusPointCollection MyStylusPointCollection = new StylusPointCollection();
          MyStylusPointCollection.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP));
          NewStroke = new Stroke(MyStylusPointCollection);
          NewStroke.DrawingAttributes.Color = drawingColor;
          NewStroke.DrawingAttributes.Height = strokeSize;
          NewStroke.DrawingAttributes.Width = strokeSize;
          MyIP.Strokes.Add(NewStroke);
          StylusPointCollection ErasePointCollection = new StylusPointCollection();                    
        }
        else if(crtState == EditState.Erase) {
           MyIP.CaptureMouse();
           StylusPointCollection pointErasePoints = e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP);
           StrokeCollection hitStrokes = MyIP.Strokes.HitTest(pointErasePoints);
           if (hitStrokes.Count > 0)
               foreach (Stroke hitStroke in hitStrokes)
                  MyIP.Strokes.Remove(hitStroke);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }    
    }

    private void MyIP_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (crtState == EditState.Erase) {
            StylusPointCollection pointErasePoints = e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP);
            StrokeCollection hitStrokes = MyIP.Strokes.HitTest(pointErasePoints);    
            if (hitStrokes.Count > 0)
                foreach (Stroke hitStroke in hitStrokes)
                    MyIP.Strokes.Remove(hitStroke); 
        }

        if (crtState==EditState.Draw && NewStroke != null)             
           NewStroke.StylusPoints.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP));
    }

    private void MyIP_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        NewStroke = null;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you use the stroke  with your canvas background color to erase ?

Comment: @asitis I am using transparent color for my canvas, because there is an image on which I want to draw stroke.